Please can I have some guidance on analysing policy change on time series data?
Firstly, I am not a statistician, merely a consumer of statistics (NHS Pharmacist).
I am undertaking a project looking at the impact of a new clinical test on antibiotic prescribing across multiple general practices.
I have access to historical data which generally shows a slow reduction in number of antibiotics prescribed with time. Additionally (which is the start of my problems) there is significant seasonality associated with antibiotic prescribing (more in the winter months).
The intervention will take place in May, and I want to evaluate the impact of prescribing beyond this point.
My current thinking is to use ITSA to try to evaluate any change in prescribing - Does this sound like a sensible approach given the seasonality of the data?
An alternative approach would presumably be Difference in Difference analysis - Where I can compare the data of the 10 or so practices that are adopting the intervention vs 10 matched practices that are not as a control.
As I said, I am not a statistician - Any help or guidance would be gratefully received.
